# How find all directories in specific path in ruby?

Tags: ruby

How find all the directories in string path

EX

```
tmp/guava/metadata/en-US/images/icon.png
```

i would like to list

- en-US
- images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine `String#split` with [`File.dirname`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/File.html#method-c-dirname):

```
path = "tmp/guava/metadata/en-US/images/icon.png"

parts = File.dirname(path).split('/')
# => ["tmp", "guava", "metadata", "en-US", "images"]

parts.last(2)
# => ["en-US", "images"]
```

Comment: What’s the reason to use `File.dirname` here? `"tmp/guava/metadata/en-US/images/icon.png".split('/')[-3...-1]` would do.

Comment: @mudasobwa It's more of a portable solution, as Windows can get pretty wonky. `File.split` only pulls off one part at a time or I'd recommend using that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` method

```
str = 'tmp/guava/metadata/en-US/images/icon.png'


str.split('/')[3] 
#=> 'en-US'

str.split('/')[4]
#=> 'images'
```

If you want list all you can do something like this:

```
    str.split('/').each { |el| puts "#{el} \n" } 
    #tmp 
    #guava 
    #metadata 
    #en-US 
    #images 
    #icon.png
```